# Find first occurrence of file in list of directories

Tags: python

I have a list of directories. In this list I want to find the first directory with a certain file and return the abspath of the file. I currently have the following code that works:

```
from os.path import exists, join, abspath

path = ["/some/where", "/some/where/else", "/another/location"]
file_name = "foo.bar"
try:
    file = [abspath(join(d, file_name)) for d in path if exists(join(d, file_name))][0]
except IndexError:
    file = ""
```

How can I do this more elegant? What i in particular dislike are the two joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pull the `join` out into a genexp:

```
>>> paths = ["/some/where", "/some/where/else", "/another/location", "/tmp"]
>>> file_name = "foo.bar"
>>> joined = (join(p, file_name) for p in paths)
>>> next((abspath(f) for f in joined if exists(f)), '')
'/tmp/foo.bar'
```

(You could trivially make this a one-liner if you wanted by inlining it.)

Note that this differs from your code because it stops after finding the first one, whereas your code finds them all.

Comment: Inlined for reference: `next((abspath(f) for f in (join(p, file_name) for p in paths) if exists(f)), '')`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you joined the the directories with the filename before hand to avoid joining twice, you are still joining **all** directories. For example, if your list has 10 directories, you will call `os.path.join()` 10 times, even if the directory which contains the file may be first in the list. Worse yet, when you have to do this several thousands or millions of times, it adds up.

I could not see any elegant solution using list comprehension, so I designed an iterative one. In my solution, as soon as we find a directory which contains the file, we immediately return the full, absolute path to that file and do not process any further. This solution is not elegant, but it is faster.

The downside of this solution is the overhead of calling a function. If what you find is at the end of the list, my solution might be slower than the list comprehension solution.

```
import os

def find_first(directories, filename):
    '''
    Given a list of directories and a file name, find first existent
    occurrence.
    '''
    for directory in directories:
        fullpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(directory, filename))
        if os.path.exists(fullpath):
            return fullpath
    return False

directories = ['/foo', '/bin', '/usr/bin']
filename = 'bash'
print find_first(directories, filename) # /bin/bash
```

Comment: This is sort of standard 10 liner code, I was asking for an elegant solution. However, this is readable, the one-liner version is not.